# How to log SSAS $system.discover_sessions to a SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssas

We are running SQL Server 2014 and SSAS on the same box.  Every now and then our SSAS service appears to freeze.  When it does I check the `msmdsrv.log` file and it tells me that *spid x* is blocking transaction on *spid y*.

Is it possible to log the results from SSAS `$System.discover_sessions` to a database on the SQL Server on a regular interval?  I'd like to capture the current session so that when these issues come up I can see the commands that are running and the SSAS instance refuses to allow me a connection when this occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You could log this periodically by scheduling an SSIS package with a data source to the SSAS server and a destination to the SQL Server but I think your better option would be to have a look at the [Flight Recorder](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3616/sql-server-analysis-services-flight-recorder/). (There unfortunately isn't an enormous amount of [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/server-properties/log-properties?view=sql-server-2017).)

Flight recorder basically captures a sort of server side trace continuously which you can then analyze (and even replay) in profiler to see what was happening at that point in time.

Alternatively you could set up a profiler/server side trace yourself or use the [ssasdiag](https://github.com/ssasdiag/SSASDiag/wiki/SSAS-Diagnostics-Tool---Collection) tool.